# How to create order in magento programmatically with paypal payment method

Tags: php, magento, paypal-sandbox

How to create order in magento programmatically with paypal payment method.

We have implemented code for COD method or Check/Money order payment methods, now I need to implement payment, I searched alot but didn't found any answer, is there a proper way for this ?

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue ? am also having same issue. can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

first of all paypal is payment getaway which need authentication .

but you can try this code

file here : app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php

function code here :

```
public function order(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
    $this->_placeOrder($payment, $amount);

    $payment->setAdditionalInformation($this->_isOrderPaymentActionKey, true);

    if ($payment->getIsFraudDetected()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $order = $payment->getOrder();
    $orderTransactionId = $payment->getTransactionId();

    $api = $this->_callDoAuthorize($amount, $payment, $payment->getTransactionId());

    $state  = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
    $status = true;

    $formatedPrice = $order->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt($amount);
    if ($payment->getIsTransactionPending()) {
        $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Ordering amount of %s is pending approval on gateway.', $formatedPrice);
        $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
    } else {
        $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Ordered amount of %s.', $formatedPrice);
    }

    $payment->addTransaction(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_ORDER, null, false, $message);

    $this->_pro->importPaymentInfo($api, $payment);

    if ($payment->getIsTransactionPending()) {
        $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Authorizing amount of %s is pending approval on gateway.', $formatedPrice);
        $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
        if ($payment->getIsFraudDetected()) {
            $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
        }
    } else {
        $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Authorized amount of %s.', $formatedPrice);
    }

    $payment->resetTransactionAdditionalInfo();

    $payment->setTransactionId($api->getTransactionId());
    $payment->setParentTransactionId($orderTransactionId);

    $transaction = $payment->addTransaction(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_AUTH, null, false,
        $message
    );

    $order->setState($state, $status);

    $payment->setSkipOrderProcessing(true);
    return $this;
}
```

you can customize this code as per you basic requirement

and let me know if you have any issue